# Extract parts of a string in Amzon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract certain elements from a URL like below (there are multiple urls like this):

https://google.com/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=c_lp_generic_us_2021-03-23&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkZiFBhD9ARIsAGxFX8AienwPdwPa_-qZnqbRzFoK98BU3VvTvdI4La5IrPW7anUaBOX5QSQaAs01EALw_wcB

I am hoping to extract the `utm_medium`, `utm_source` and `utm_campaign` from the URL

The output should be 4 columns

- URL (above url)
- utm_medium = cpc
- utm_source= google
- utm_campaign = c_lp_generic_us_2021-03-23

How the urls are contrived with the utm_medium, utm_source and utm_campaign format wont change so I am hoping they can be used as some sort of reference point

Comment: Use `substring` with regular expressions as seen in the documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

In postgres

```
with cte as (
select 'https://google.com/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=c_lp_generic_us_2021-03-23&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkZiFBhD9ARIsAGxFX8AienwPdwPa_-qZnqbRzFoK98BU3VvTvdI4La5IrPW7anUaBOX5QSQaAs01EALw_wcB' url_
)
select 
split_part(url_,'?',1),
max(split_part(t.split_,'=',2)) filter(where split_part(t.split_,'=',1)='utm_medium') "utm_medium",
max(split_part(t.split_,'=',2)) filter(where split_part(t.split_,'=',1)='utm_source') "utm_source",
max(split_part(t.split_,'=',2)) filter(where split_part(t.split_,'=',1)='utm_campaign') "utm_campaign"
from cte cross join lateral 

regexp_split_to_table(split_part(url_,'?',2),'&') t(split_)
group by 1
```

EDIT as per comment:
In `postgresql` and `redshift` both

```
with cte as (
select 'https://google.com/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=c_lp_generic_us_2021-03-23&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkZiFBhD9ARIsAGxFX8AienwPdwPa_-qZnqbRzFoK98BU3VvTvdI4La5IrPW7anUaBOX5QSQaAs01EALw_wcB' url_
)
select 
split_part(url_,'?',1),
substring(split_part(url_,'utm_medium=',2),1,position('&' in split_part(url_,'utm_medium=',2))-1) "utm_medium",
substring(split_part(url_,'utm_source=',2),1,position('&' in split_part(url_,'utm_source=',2))-1) "utm_source",
substring(split_part(url_,'utm_campaign=',2),1,position('&' in split_part(url_,'utm_campaign=',2))-1) "utm_campaign"
from cte
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1a20434f5d76cfa9a40a8a1e5db995d9)

Comment: Thank you! However I am getting a syntax error near filter(where... (line 6). I am pulling a redshift database.

Comment: You are getting error because you are not using postgresql. DEMO. If you are using redshift then tag correct database in your question. Redshift and postgres is different database. Added answer with redshift also

Comment: thank you so much, as I see in your demo it works correctly as you say (apologies for my confusing question.) When running this query in tabelplus I still get an error though:
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 10: regexp_split_to_table (split_part(url_,'?',2),'&') t(split_)...

Super frustrating... I'm quite new to this.

Comment: thank you - sorry I am now getting another error: Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from "unknown" to text

Answer (score 0):

The above split_part works good. If you need another way you can use it the below way.

```
select substring('https://google.com/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=c_lp_generic_us_2021-03-23' 
from  position('utm_medium=' IN 'https://google.com/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=c_lp_generic_us_2021-03-23') +11
for position('&utm_source' IN 'https://google.com/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=c_lp_generic_us_2021-03-23') - 
(position('utm_medium=' IN 'https://google.com/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=c_lp_generic_us_2021-03-23') + 11) )
```